# How to get binding value in input hidden value Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have file upload and I can upload file then get controller value put in input hidden value because I will be post form.

HTML CODE

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="i_file5" file-model="process.step.file5" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files5)" />
<input type="hidden" ng-model="{{files.name}}"/>
```

Controller Code

```
$scope.uploadResult = [];
        $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
            //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
            for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
                var $file = $files[i];
                $upload.upload({
                    url: 'lib/fileupload/',
                    file: $file,
                    progress: function(e){}
                }).then(function(response) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.uploadResult.push(response.data);
                        console.log($scope.uploadResult);
                    });
                }); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have already specify controller in HTML. If not please implement as shown in below example. For ng-model you should not use `{{ }}` as you are binding the value not evaluating it.

```
<div ng-controller="files">
----
<input type="text" data-ng-model="files.name" style="display:none"/>

</div>
```

Comment: agree.. modified my answer

Comment: Yes I agree with you.. Thanks :)